# I am not able to open database and query on it

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

**strong text**

I am not able to open database and query on it. i want to access row of table that is passed from a different java file using intent value. Please help !

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Finish_kitchen extends Activity {
    GridView gridView;
    private imageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private static String DB_Path = "/mnt/sdcard/Kitchen_Data.db";
    private Cursor c;
    private String path;
    private ListView listView1;
    private ArrayList<String> Steps;
    private ArrayList<String> Image_path;
    private ArrayList<String> Audio_path;
    private int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.finish_kit);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        Steps = new ArrayList<String>();
        Image_path = new ArrayList<String>();
        Audio_path = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_Path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        c = db.query(path, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        Steps.add(c.getString(1));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "heyaa gotcha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

> 04-04 11:50:02.411: D/PackageItemInfo(26824):
>   loadIcon(cached)name=org.example.beproj.MainActivity
>       04-04 11:50:49.752: D/skia(26824): new locale 
>       04-04 11:50:54.116: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26824): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
>       04-04 11:52:06.674: W/MediaRecorder(26824): mediarecorder went away with unhandled events
>       04-04 11:52:12.390: E/SQLiteLog(26824): (1) near "/": syntax error
>       04-04 11:52:12.390: D/AndroidRuntime(26824): Shutting down VM
>       04-04 11:52:12.390: W/dalvikvm(26824): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b11ae0)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{org.example.beproj/org.example.beproj.Finish_kitchen}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM /storage/sdcard0/Kitchen/mnvx
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM /storage/sdcard0/Kitchen/mnvx
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:888)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:499)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at org.example.beproj.Finish_kitchen.onCreate(Finish_kitchen.java:50)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5117)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
>       04-04 11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824):  ... 11 more
>       04-04 11:52:14.922: I/Process(26824): Sending signal. PID: 26824 SIG: 9

Comment: cursor thing is not working properly!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM /storage/sdcard0/Kitchen/mnvx` see this. you can not query like this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
c = db.query(path, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

First parameter should be your table name. But you are giving a file  path.

Here is the error message-

```
11:52:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(26824): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM /storage/sdcard0/Kitchen/mnvx
```